# Binary response via Python Mangum through AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, fastapi, mangum

Mangum documentation states that binary responses are by default: https://mangum.io/http/#configuring-binary-responses
But I simply can't get it to work, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```py
import random
    
from fastapi import APIRouter, Response
from fastapi.middleware.gzip import GZipMiddleware
    
router = APIRouter(tags=['public'])
    
app = create_app()
app.add_middleware(GZipMiddleware, minimum_size=1000)
    
# AWS Lambda support
handler = Mangum(app, lifespan="off")
    
    
@router.get("/update/{current_state}/download")
async def download_something_binary() -> Response:
    # Create some random bytes
    import random
    open('/tmp/data', 'wb').write(random.randbytes(1024 * 100))

    # Return the binary payload
    f = open('/tmp/data', 'rb')
    return Response(
        status_code=200,
        content=f.read(), headers={
                "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=data.tar.gz"})
```

I have also tried returning just a dict.

All the time I get the data out on the client as base64 encoded data.

As I understand, Mangum should automatically figure out if the Content-Type is not one of the text_mime_types that it should set the isBase64Encoded json key in the response body to true for API Gateway to understand to convert it to binary at the client side.

Have I misunderstood something or am I doing something wrong here? please help.

Comment: I have only a hunch to offer: what type of API Gateway are you using and is it configured to support binary responses?

Comment: Hi Erik. You were right, I needed to add the binary media type